# Can I apply z-test after MonteCarlo sampling

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, monte-carlo

I'm trying to compare whether two datasets come from the same distribution, and to do this I was thinking of using the z-test. However, the data is not normally distributed, and to fix this I was thinking of taking a big number(1000) of random samples with repetition, and to take the mean of the elements in each sample.

According to the Central Limit Theorem this will result in a normal distribution, however I'm not sure whether it will be valid analysis if I apply the z-test to this new dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such an approach lacks statistical power and will not detect differences in the shapes of the distribution.  For instance, you can generate realizations from an exponential distribution with mean $1$, and a normal distribution with mean $1$, and their sample means will be similar for sufficiently large sample sizes, but they have very different distributions.

Instead, you would perform a [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test), or some other similar test comparing empirical distributions.

Comment: Hello heropup, thank you very much for your response, but I would like to ask whether somewhat different sampling test is valid if it is not a problem, since I saw this on one place but it also doesn't look very valid: So we combine both datasets and we create samples of sizes n_1 and n_2 and compare the differences of means of those two subsets to the difference of means of the starting datasets. We then calculate the p-value as (COUNTS_BIGGER) / (TOTAL_SAMPLES). Our data is discrete and of size around 1000 combined